# M600/A3 uart problems

Tags: dji-sdk

I'm eventually trying to use transparent data transmission to pass messages between the mobile SDK and an onboard device using the A3 API/UART port.

Right now I used DJI assistant to output a timestamp to the API port at 1hz. When I connect a TTL>USB device, I see garbage data coming through. When I connect an oscilloscope with a protocol analyzer, I see one frame every second, but the frame is variable size. The ASCII representation of what does come through is nonsense.

I have double checked that baud is set correctly (and have tried other baud rates). I've made sure the grounding is proper. I've tried probing the pin on the actual A3 port (to remove possibility of EMI on the serial cable). It seems like I'm getting garbage data on the serial line, or I don't know how to decode it properly.

Answer (score 0):

Hi，maybe you can refer to the open-protocol of M100  [Link](https://developer.dji.com/onboard-sdk/documentation/protocol-doc/open-protocol.html).I think it's difficult to decode the protocol of N3,unless DJI publishes that。